# VUEX подскажите что я делаю не так?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Есть модуль store
 папка modules  в ней папка change-form,
 там файлы action.js

```
 export function FORM_CHANGE({commit}) {
  commit('SET_FORM')
}
```

getters.js

```
export function GET_FORM(state) {
  return state.chForm
}

mutation.js 



   export function SET_CHANGE_FORM(state) {
        state.chForm = 'FormReg'
    }

state.js
```

export const state = () => ({
  chForm: 'FormAuth'
});

index.js

```
import * as actions from './actions';
import * as mutations from './mutations';
import * as getters from './getters';
import { state } from './state';

export default {
   namespaced: true,
    mutations,
    actions,
    state,
    getters,
};
```

и index.js в самой папке store

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Vuex from "vuex"

import changeForm from "./modules/change-form/index"

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    changeForm
  }


});

export default store;
```

на девтулс base State [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в компоненте undefined [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл где подгружаются формы: Auth.vue

```
<script>
  import FormAuth from "../components/FormAuth";
  import FormReg from "../components/FormReg";
  import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex"


  export default {
    name: "Auth",
    data() {
      return {}
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters([
        'GET_FORM'
      ])
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions([
        'modules'
      ]),
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    components: {
      FormAuth,
      FormReg
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: А почему не указано имя модуля в mapGetters? Вы же включили неймспейсы.

Comment: @t0lik благодарю всё заработало